# Firebase Sharing: Large number of connections ( 100K+ ) but same data tree

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So here is the situation. What if you are going to have > 100K simultaneous connections and you need all users to see the same data tree. I know that FirebaseDB (FDB) recommends sharding, however this does not fully make sense to me since you can not query across multiple databases.

For example, say you have a list of items in the tree:

```
{
    "grocery_list": {
      "item-1": "apple",
      // thousands of items.
    }
}
```

So if I shard this list, to see the full list I would need to look at both databases. Thus, if I have 150K users, this still means to me each database could at some point potentially have more than 100K connections, so I don't see how sharding fixes the issue if you need all clients to have the same data.

The solution I'm looking it is a "double-write", meaning, I write the same data to both DB's, but shard connections to stay under 100K. I just want to be sure this is a sound approach.

Comment: Does this same one `grocery_list` need to be accessed by **all** of your users? Does each user need to access all the thousand items in the list?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to go over the 100k limit, I would recommend using [Firebase Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/products/firestore/) instead. Right now its in Beta, but soon enough, it will come out of Beta and there will be no 100k limit. Also, its much more advanced and better to use then Realtime Database.